# Why does my iPad keep asking for my iCloud password?

Tags: ipad, icloud, password

I keep receiving an iCloud pop-up message to insert my iCloud password every time i switch on my iPad and I'm unable to do anything on it, inserting the password doesn't help. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to solve this issue is going to your **Settings**

- Go to iCloud
- Log out
- Log back in

Your issue should be solved now. If not, you might have installed apps via another Apple Id which is prompting you to enter its password.

Comment: Except that there's no way to log out of my iCloud account that I can see (iPad 2/System 7.1.2), only delete it.