# How do I stop getting password notifications from iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have been having this weird issue where my phone keeps asking for my iCloud password.  I enter the password but then it says the password is locked.

Is there a way I can fix this or get rid of all the nonfictions it keeps giving me?

My iPhone has been doing this way more often since the iOS 10.0.2 update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my iPad keep asking for my iCloud password?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128868/why-does-my-ipad-keep-asking-for-my-icloud-password)

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple KB : If your Apple ID is locked](https://support.apple.com/HT204106)

> ## If your Apple ID is locked
>
> If you or someone else enters your password, security questions, or
> other account information incorrectly too many times, your Apple ID
> automatically locks to protect your security and you can't sign in to
> any Apple services. You can unlock your Apple ID after you verify your
> identity.
>
> If your Apple ID is locked for security reasons, you might see one of
> these alerts:
>
> - “This Apple ID has been disabled for security reasons”
> - "You can't sign in because your account was disabled for security reasons"
> - "This Apple ID has been locked for security reasons"
>
> When you see one of these alerts, you can go to [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/)
> to unlock your account with your existing password or to [reset your
> password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487). After multiple unsuccessful attempts to unlock your
> account, your Apple ID will remain locked and you can try again the
> next day.
>
> If you use [two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152), you need to use your recovery
> key and a trusted device. And if you use [two-factor
> authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915), you need a trusted device or trusted phone number
> to unlock your Apple ID.
>
> If you see a message that is different from the alerts above and you
> can't reset your password, contact Apple for help.